# Disable OpenCV-core's output "Init done"

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I just updated my opencv to the latest stable version (3.1.0). I tried to run a programm on which i'm working for a long time now, and everything works fine.

But I've got a new output 'Init done - Opengl support available'coming from Qt or OpenCV I don't really know, when I'm displaying an image. I would like to disable that output, because I've already a lot of outputs of mine.

If you have a quick solution (I mean easy to process), it would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at the relevant code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/c3eb1254cfa04cb8cf61de71bfba628caac3cfe8/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp#L463-L479), this output is only triggered if there is no `QApplication` instance already present. You can stop the output by creating a `QApplication` instance before doing any OpenCV related operations:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Perform highgui operations.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it was exactly that :)